# SOLR current position on list

Tags: solr

How can i add position of item on list searched in solr?

query with offset 10 limit 10:

```
<doc>
<position>10</position>
[...]
</doc>
<doc>
<position>11</position>
[...]
</doc>
<doc>
<position>12</position>
[...]
</doc>
[...]
```

query with offset 5 limit 10:

```
<doc>
<position>5</position>
[..]
</doc>
<doc>
<position>6</position>
[...]
</doc>
<doc>
<position>7</position>
[...]
</doc>
[...]
```

I need it in front-end, and i dont want to iterate through all data... is there a way to add it in SOLR?

Comment: Just manipulate the results you get from your Solr client, it's trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it appears you are looking for **Ordinal Ranking Strategy** [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Ordinal_ranking_.28.221234.22_ranking.29)

Yes, you could do this via Solr. For a sequence of ordinal numbers, it may be an overkill to create a custom Solr component to achieve this. But if you are exposing your Solr servers directly to your client application & if you don't have an application layer that wraps your Solr Server you can write a simple plugin to achieve this. Here is a primer on Solr Plugin [SolrPlugins](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins)

**Note:** I am in process of open sourcing a Solr Plugin that implements various ranking strategies [Ranking Strategies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking) but it is in **beta** state. The plugin could do ordinal ranking among various other ranking strategies. Here is a link to the project [Project](https://github.com/ausathya/Solr-Ranking-Plugin)